# Entity Framework. Помогите с архитектурой

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Задача. Есть база фильмов (фильм имеет различные поля, в данном контексте не имеет значение какие). В частности, фильм имеет коллекцию жанров. То есть еще существует таблица с жанрами и таблица для связи фильма и жанра "многие ко многим".

Делаю приложение WPF. Базой рулит отдельная библиотека классов. Чтобы оградить проект UI от EF, я решил сделать отдельный класс-адаптер (**вопрос первый, нужен ли он или это плохая практика?**). Адаптер инстансный. В адаптере создается контекст данных. Получается, что в рамках приложения я имею один экземпляр адаптера (а значит и один экземпляр контекста данных). **Вопрос второй, это нормально? Ведь если каждый раз создавать новый контекст, приложение будет очень долго думать.** При таком подходе у меня возникает еще проблема с сохранением данных. Ну например я открыл 2 формы, одна для редактирования информации о фильме, другая для редактирования набора жанров. И если я в форме редактирования жанров нажму "Сохранить" (то есть отправлю команду _context.SaveChanges()), то в базу занесутся и изменения, которые я внес, редактируя фильм (они ведь сделаны в одном контексте). **Вопрос третий, как правильно работать с данными, чтобы такого не происходило?** И вообще я не могу придумать, как прикрутить это все по человечески на MVVM. Пока что говнокодингом занимаюсь. :( В общем то это был четвертый вопрос. **Как прикрутить это все на MVVM?** Ко всему прочему мне нужен постраничный вывод. Пока приходит в голову только способ  `context.EntitySet.Skip(a).Take(b)`. И вот тут тоже вопрос. **Правильно ли это? Не будет ли такой подход вызывать запрос всех предыдущих до скипа значений, прежде чем вернуть мне нужный набор?**

**UPD:**

Мои изыскания привели меня вот к чему

1. Адаптер все же нужен, хотя бы для того, чтобы оградить проект UI от работы с Entity Framework.
2. Контекст в первый раз создается долго и долго делает первый запрос (по крайней мере один и тот же запрос к одному сету). Каждый следующий раз он использует данные из кэша.
3. Благодаря вопросу 2, вопрос 3 отпал. Но появился новый вопрос. Я делаю изменение данных в экземпляре контекста. Данные сохраняются. Я изменяю их извне, затем получаю все в том же контексте и он не подтягивает сторонние изменения. То есть он показывает старые данные. **Как сказать ему, чтобы он сделал новый запрос?**

Остались открытыми вопросы 4 и 5.

Получить данные постранично для MSSQL для меня было не то что бы проблематично, но не особо приятно (приходилось кидать в процедуру запрос в виде текста), либо запрос происходил довольно долго (с большими объемами данных). В данный момент я работаю с SQLite. В общем вопрос оптимизации и все такое. Если кто-то точно уверен, что EF в данном случае адекватно запрашивает постраничные данные, отпишитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: Первое - кажется, плохая. Skip/Take - вроде он должен сам разобраться, если ты его за своим интерфейсом не прячешь. Остальные - не знаю.

Comment: @Qwertiy, блин, где все эти люди, кто успешно пользуется EF? Слышу только абстрактные фразочки о том как он полезен. В интернетах куча примеров аля ЗАКАЗ -- ЗАКАЗЧИК, но они настолько простые, что даже рассматривать не стоит. А как начинаю искать интересующие конкретные вопросы, так фиг найдешь и никто ниче не знает :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, а если первое решение плохое, то как мне отделить UI от работы с EF? Я хочу оперировать только моделями (Film, Genre) и их коллекциями. Для этого ведь не нужен EF. Модели - обычные классы. В общем расскажите ваши мысли по этому поводу.

Comment: Считай, что она bll и просто наматывай сверху linq - вроде так принято :)

Answer (score -2):

> Чтобы оградить проект UI от EF, я решил сделать отдельный класс-адаптер
>   Просто можно использовать класс для контекста данных.

Если каждый раз создавать новый контекст, то почти ничего не изменится. Сейчас мощности вычислительной техники хватает, что бы создавать контекст постоянно. Можно создавать глобальную переменую для контекста и использовать её.

> При таком подходе у меня возникает еще проблема с сохранением данных. Ну например я открыл 2 формы, одна для редактирования информации о фильме, другая для редактирования набора жанров. И если я в форме редактирования жанров нажму "Сохранить" (то есть отправлю команду _context.SaveChanges()), то в базу занесутся и изменения, которые я внес, редактируя фильм (они ведь сделаны в одном контексте).

Проблема с сохранениями не должна быть. Имеется 2 открытых формы и разные события для сохранения информации с форм. Нужно что бы *context.Таблица.Add(ДАННЫЕ);* и *context.SaveChanges();* были в событие нажатия кнопки "Сохранить".

*context.EntitySet.Skip(a).Take(b)* - при таком запросе будет создан запрос к базе данных и он вернет только нужную выборку.

Comment: События то разные, но context.SaveChanges() будут одинаковые. Контекст то один. По поводу контекста, тут проблема не в создании, а в том, что первый запрос даже из маленькой таблицы выполняется долго (наверное запрос формируется в первый раз). `context.EntitySet.Skip(a).Take(b)` вернет столько данных, сколько нужно. Вопрос в том, какой запрос он при этом сформирует? Не получится ли так, что запрос будет плохо оптимизирован?